# Batch script to read keys and update value

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
{
    "productVersion": "1.7.0",
    "examplePath": "somepath",
    "exampleBootloaderScript": "addin.js",
    "cachePath": "%APPDATA%\\example\\example",
    "logPath": "%APPDATA%\\example\\example\\Product\\Logs",
    "logLevel": "Info",
    "tempExcelCachePath": "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\example\\example5\\Cache",
    "exampleArgs": [
        "--devmenu",
        "--allow-insecure-localhost"
    ]
}
```

I want to read the above file and update the value for key `examplePath` to this:

```
{
    "productVersion": "1.7.0",
    "examplePath": "D:\workspace\e5\sample\src\products\sample",
    "exampleBootloaderScript": "addin.js",
    "cachePath": "%APPDATA%\\example\\example",
    "logPath": "%APPDATA%\\example\\example\\Product\\Logs",
    "logLevel": "Info",
    "tempExcelCachePath": "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\example\\example5\\Cache",
    "exampleArgs": [
        "--devmenu",
        "--allow-insecure-localhost"
    ]
}
```

How do I do this using bat file?

Comment: Will `somepath` be static or can it be anything?

Comment: Please post the content of the [tag:batch-file] you would like us to help you to fix a specific issue with. Also can you please tell us what the encoding of the file requiring modification is and whether it uses `LF`, `CR` or `CRLF` line endings. If there are any environment restrictions we must take account of when suggesting possible solutions, please mention them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `somepath` will be static always:

```
@echo off
set "_infile=YOURFILENAME HERE"
set "_strfind=somepath"
set "_strinsert=D:\workspace\e5\sample\src\products\sample"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=]" %%a in ('type "%_infile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%_infile%"') do (
        set "str=%%a"
        call set "str=%%str:%_strfind%=%_strinsert%%%"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!str! >>%_infile%
        endlocal
)
type %_infile%
```

If `somepath` can be anything, we need to be more specific and focus on the key, therefore this will ONLY work if the file is in the exact format as you have posted! As we take the key by position in the string.

So before you continue, make a **Backup** of your file as this will break it if your format is not what you posted.

```
@echo off
set "_infile=YOURFILENAME HERE"
set "_strfind=examplePath"
set "_strinsert=    "examplePath": "D:\workspace\e5\sample\src\products\sample!","
for /f "tokens=2 delims=]" %%a in ('type "%_infile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%_infile%"') do (
        set "str=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if "!str:~5,11!"=="%_strfind%" (
            setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
            set "str=%_strinsert%"
        )
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!str! >>%_infile%
        endlocal
)
type %_infile%
```

Lastly, the reason why I use `delayedexpansion` in certain parts is purely to cater for lines that contains `!`.